# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: flutter

After the flutter 1.17 update, I tried to run my app, but it shows this error. `flutter doctor` command works fine. I don't understand what is happening

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 7 Pro in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not download arm64_v8a_debug.jar (io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-540786dd51f112885a89792d678296b95e6622e5)
      > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-540786dd51f112885a89792d678296b95e6622e5/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-540786dd51f112885a89792d678296b95e6622e5.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-540786dd51f112885a89792d678296b95e6622e5/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-540786dd51f112885a89792d678296b95e6622e5.jar'.
            > Remote host closed connection during handshake

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: are you behind any proxy?

Comment: or a firewall??

Comment: No. It was downloading patch sdk. I used a VPN to do that though

Comment: can you try without any VPN.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I met with a similar problem of unavailability of kotlin sdk resources. Couldn't find a quick solution, but the **problem was most likely on the server side** with resources. Because the next morning, the whole assembly was successful.
Perhaps you should **just wait**, if before that everything was going fine and suddenly stopped.

After reading the entire branch, I still did not find a solution for my case, but it may be useful to someone.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23553

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and it was resolved when I changed the following settings in my build.gradle file:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61' //from 1.3.50
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3' //from 3.5.0
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```